# Prisma/React Query Dependent undefined type challenges

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, react-query, trpc

I would like to take the output of one query (a TRPC query on Prisma) and use this as the dependent input in a future query.

I followed the dependent documentation for React Query but running into type errors that the return of the first may possibly be undefined (e.g. `product is possibly 'undefined'`):

```
  const { data: product } = api.product.getUnique.useQuery({ id: pid });

  const options = api.option.getAll.useQuery(
    {
      product: product.productSize,
      region: product.productRegion,
    },
    { enabled: !!product }
  );
```

Does the inclusion of enabled not already handle this? If not, what is the correct way to adapt for Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Just casting the `product` value as a boolean return any *truthy* value (f.e if `product` will be equal to `{}` it will still result in `true`, that means that `product` won't necessarily have the `productSize` or `productRegion` properties, I would change it first to:

`{ enabled: !!product && product.productSize && product.productRegion }`

If that doesn't fix the typescript error, you as a developer can know for sure that the values are actually there so what you can use the `as` keyword in typescript to tell it that you know for sure that the type is what you want it to be:
(In this example I assumed that the values are string but you can change it to number or whatever the true value of them are)

```
const options = api.option.getAll.useQuery(
    {
      product: product.productSize as string,
      region: product.productRegion as string,
    },
    { enabled: !!product && product.productSize && product.productRegion }
  );
```